# Получение данных для обоих ключей в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE match(
  id int,
  home_id int,
  away_id int,
  date date,
  home_score int,
  away_score int,
  uuid int,
);

INSERT INTO match VALUES
(1, 3, 4, '01.02.2022', 5, 3, 1234),
(2, 6, 7, '02.03.2022', 3, 1, 5678)
(3, 7, 3, '03.04.2022', 1, 2, 1424)
(4, 9, 10, '04.05.2022', 2, 7, 4212)
(5, 12, 11, '05.06.2022', 3, 1, 9232)
```

Матчи

```
id home_id away_id date       home_score away_score uuid
1  3       4       01.02.2022 5          2          1234
2  6       7       02.03.2022 3          1          5678
3  7       3       03.04.2022 1          2          1424
4  9       10      04.05.2022 2          7          4212
5  12      11      05.06.2022 3          1          9232
```

Что я хочу, так это получить данные для обеих ключей home_id и away_id одного матча в одном запросе по uuid. Данные включают в себя очки home и away команды, а также дата матча за последние 5 матчей. Пытался сделать так:

```
SELECT m1.score, m2.score
FROM match m1
JOIN (
    SELECT m.home_id as home_team, m.away_id as away_team
    FROM match m
    WHERE m.uuid = 1234
) sub
ON sub.home_team = m1.home_id
JOIN match m2
ON sub.away_team = m2.away_id
```

Но получаю кучу данных, которые по айди группировать не выходит. Искомый результат выглядит так:

```
home_id home_score home_date  away_id away_score away_date
1       5          01.01.2022 3       2          02.03.2022
1       3          05.03.2022 3       4          03.05.2022
1       2          07.03.2022 3       1          04.06.2022
```

То есть, айди home команды, её очки и дата матча, тоже самое для команды away.

Comment: `home_id` и `away_id` независимы - так что для каждого требуется своя независимая копия исходной таблицы.

Comment: *Искомый результат выглядит примерно так:* Покажите результат, который ТОЧНО соответствует показанным исходным данным. И укажите точное значение использованного для этого результата критерия `uuid`.